# Как сделать так , когда я напишу в терминал 0 , он отвечал мне 0, а не " Четное "

Tags: python, if

```py
n = int(input("Введетие число:"))
if n % 2 == 0:
    print('Четное')
else:
    print('Нечетное')
```

Comment: `if n == 0: ...`

Answer (score 0):

elif - иначе если, это как else, просто в нём может быть условие

```
if n == 0:
    print('0')
elif n % 2 == 0:
    print('Четное')
else:
    print('Нечетное')
```